# c# getting average of array, but white space returns 0, and blank is an error

Tags: c#, average

I am working on c# code where I am getting the average of numbers in an array, and I am having an issue that when there is a whitespace in the array it isnt being recognized. And then for a completely empty array it is supposed to return an error message. I am not sure how to resolve this issue.
if there is a whitespace it is supposed to be "0.00"

c# code:

```
public double Average(int[] scores)
        {   
            foreach (double num in scores){

                if (num >= 0 ){
                    double sum = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
                    {
                        sum += scores[i];
                    }   
                    double average = sum / scores.Length; 
                    return average;
                }
            }
        throw new NotImplementedException("scores must be positive");
    }
```

Comment: How could an integer array have a 'whitespace'.. Can you share the error you're getting ?

Comment: @PaulKaram its just seeing the whitespace as not a positive value, do you think maybe I should find a way to replace the white space with a 0? "Given I have an empty array, when I call the average function, then 0.00 is returned."

Comment: Do you mean by whitespace an empty array with no values ?

Comment: Please please explain where whitespace and blanks are involved. Are you talking about other parts of the code where maybe you have a list of strings that get converted into integers or doubles?

Comment: Your description and your posted code don't line up. You say "the array isn't being recognized", but don't elaborate where or how. Your description mentions "white space", but there's no mention of strings in your code. Your code shows an exception being thrown saying "scores must be positive", what's that about?

Comment: I feel like the confusion here simply stems from...`0` is the number zero, not "whitespace".  Whitespace consists of familiar characters such as space and tab, among others.  Characters are represented with the `char` type, and a `string` stores a sequence of 0 or more `char`s.  Though a `char` can be converted to an `int` (for example, `' '` → `32`) or even a `double` (though I can't imagine the use of doing the latter), numeric values of types such as `int` and `double` are, otherwise, **not** whitespace nor are they referred to as "whitespace".

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your explanation in the comments, then you just have logical errors in your code. It could be fixed this way:

```
public double Average(int[] scores)
{
    if (scores == null || scores.Length == 0)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }

    double sum = 0;
    foreach (double num in scores)
    {
        if (num < 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("All scores must be positive");
        }

        sum += num;
    }

    return sum / scores.Length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if by whitespace you mean int[] is an empty array, then just change your error logic a bit. If by whitespace you are referring to your input data (in programming whitespace is a collection of spaces/tabs in a string, e.g. "   ") then you have to show us the code that generates the int[] array.

Also your error and return logic are in weird places, mentally stepping through your code can help

```
    public double Average(int[] scores)
    {
        if (scores == null || scores.Length == 0)
            throw new Exception("Must have values");//can return something here instead
        double sum = 0;
        foreach (double num in scores)
        {
            if (num >= 0)
                sum += num;
            else //I think your error belongs here instead
                throw new ArgumentException("scores must be positive");
        }
        
        return sum / scores.Length;
    }
```

Comment: Slight optimization (goes for Paul as well), first if statement can be `(scores?.Length is 0 or null)`.

Comment: @gunr2171 For a user and question that can both be described as "vconfusedrn", I think the straightforward, works-with-every-version-of-the-compiler way it's written here would be preferable.

Comment: @gunr2171 I had no idea you could use 'is' in that way, if I were optimising I'd do !(scores?.Length > 0) personally (that is/or stuff scares me lol), but as lance said I did the easiest to read option. Thanks for the tip though, today I learned something new

Comment: I agree with Lance though, this is just an _option_ you can do, depending on your knowledge of the language and what you feel is correct for maintenance.

Comment: I appreciated it haha @gunr2171 Always happy to learn new toys to maybe play with one day

Answer (score 0):

Your whitespace issue is not in the code you posted, but in whatever code is used to build the int[] array beforehand. Any int you get from the int[] array has already been converted into a number and can no longer be checked for whitespace or the like.

The code you have posted has its own issues, though. You need to use the foreach loop or the for loop but not both, and if you go with the for loop, you’ll need to move the negative number check inside it.

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0, 0 , 0 };

if (array1.Any(i => i < 0))
{
 throw new InvalidOperationException("All scores must be positive");
}

return (int)array1.Where(i => i > 0).Average();
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally not well-regarded, particularly in a case such as this where what the author of the question really needs is _understanding_.  That you haven't explained what you changed and why is not helpful to them, nor is introducing LINQ when they're already struggling with the loops on which it is based.  You're also iterating `array1` (at most) twice when only (at most) once is necessary, and for some reason casting the result, an average of `int`s, itself to an `int`.

Comment: on top of Lance's comment, your code only answer casts to int for some reason

Comment: `return` outside function call also looks really bad.