# c# using VS code and method testing array averages, not able to return errors

Tags: c#, xunit

I am working in VS code and using tests in another file that reference code I have written. The code is about getting the averages of arrays with doubles that have two decimal places, but if there is a negative in the array I should get an error.

Here is a working test that shows the correct output:

```
[Fact]
        public void normalArray()
        {
            int[] input = {10, 4, 2, 64, 27};
            double expected = 21.40;            
            double actual = csharpLogic.Average(input);
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
```

and then this is what I am trying to get to work:

```
[Fact]
        public void negativeArray()
        {
            int[] input = {12, 23, -4, 63};
            double actual = csharpLogic.Average(input);
            Assert.True(actual);
        }
```

this is my first time working with these so i am a bit confused with all of this.

Comment: http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Testing-for-Thrown-Exceptions-in-xUnitnet It seems like the real question here is "How do I assert that my `csharpLogic.Average(input)` statement throws an exception using XUnit?"

Comment: [More context about the method under test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610803/c-sharp-getting-average-of-array-but-white-space-returns-0-and-blank-is-an-err), but you should really include the method in this post as well to form a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can assert that the method throws a particular exception as follows

```
        [Fact]
        public void negativeArray()
        {
            int[] input = {12, 23, -4, 63};
            Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => csharpLogic.Average(input));
        }
```

You should replace `Exception` by the exact type of exception you are expecting from your method in this situation.